# Conditions on angles between three points on a sphere (which are uniformly distributed)

Tags: calculus, probability, uniform-distribution, independence

> **Question:** Let $A,B,C$ be three random, uniformly distributed, independent points on a sphere. What is the probability that none of these three points is at an angle superior than $\pi/2$ from the two others.

As of right now, I know that wlog, we can assume that $A$ is on the north pole and that $B$ is on a great circle passing through the north and south pole. Then, I am trying to calculate the area which *isn't* covered by the northern hemisphere or by the hemisphere centered at $B$. I have trouble figuring out how to deal clearly with all of these cases.

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: As you say, put $A$ on the north pole.  Then $B$ falls w.l.o.g. on "longitude" $0$.  However, note that its "latitude" isn't uniformly distributed; it is more likely to be closer to the equator than not.  (Concentration of measure, q.v.)  Let its PDF be denoted by $f(x)$, where $0 \leq x \leq \pi$.  Once the latitude of $B$ is fixed, you can now find the surface area of overlap between the hemisphere centered on $A$ and the hemisphere centered on $B$.  Call this area $s(x)$.  Then you are looking for $\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} f(x) \frac{s(x)}{4\pi}\,dx$.